# Query comparisons with null field

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore collection has documents with a string field, which can be *null*.

I was expecting that if I query:

```
Collection("products").Where("producedDate", "<", "2018-01-15")
```

I would get all products whose "producedDate" is earlier than "2018-10-15", including those whose "producedDate" is null.

But actually I am not getting the `null`s.

Is this intended or it's a bug?

Comment: This seems like a question for the Firestore maintainers or perhaps a Firestore-specific support forum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was intended to work that way. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#value_type_ordering) states that:

> When a query involves a field with **values of mixed types**, Cloud
>   Firestore uses a deterministic ordering based on the internal
>   representations. The following list shows the order:
>
> 1. Null values
> 2. Boolean values
> 3. Integer and floating-point values, sorted in numerical order
> 4. Date values
> 5. Text string values
> 6. [...]

Note that it only follows this order when you're running a query with values of mixed types. In your query you're passing a `Date` value, which means it will only query on **values of** `Date` **type** and not the others (like `null` for example).

In order to get the `null` values, you can create a compound query, by adding a second `Where`:

```
Collection("products").Where("producedDate", "<", "2018-01-15").Where("producedDate", "==", null)
```

Comment: Remember that you can always [submit a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)