# Firestore select where is not null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase to manage my project and I cannot get to create a query with a where clause where some value is not null.

Example: I have a collection of employees. Each have a list of equipments as an object where the key is the equipment id and the value a color.

```
user = {
    firstName: 'blabla',
    lastName: 'bloblo',
    equipments: {
        123: 'blue',
        124: 'red'
    }
}
```

I would like to get all the employees who has a certain equipment in the equipments. Lets say 123.

It comes to Select * from Employees where equipments.123 is not null. I've tried:

```
firestore.collection('employees').where(`equipments.${equipmentId}`, '!=', null)
```

but it's not working.

I can't seems to make it work. Can you help me.

Comment: Cloud Firestore has no "not equal" operator. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251919/firestore-how-to-perform-a-query-with-inequality-not-equals

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned, there's no "not equal" operator, but a workaround just crossed my mind. Can you try using `firestore.collection('employees').where('equipments.${equipmentId}', '<', '\uf8ff')`. I've never tested this, but I believe it's worth a shot.

Comment: Oops... I misread as a "where not exists". A "where exists" is indeed often feasible. Sounds like an answer @RosárioPereiraFernandes! :-)

Comment: Im just checking for any field in the non-existing document (field named e.g. .exists) if it equals true

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Update Sep 2020:** [v7.21.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore) introduces support for not equals (`!=`) queries!
That means you can now use the code bellow:

```js
firestore.collection('employees').where(`equipments.${equipm‌​entId}`, '!=', null)
```

---

**Previous answer:**

Firestore has no "not equal" operator. But looking at the logic, what you're trying to do is query for values which are `String`, and not `null`. [Firestore can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48271934/5861618) if you pass a String to the `where()` function.

So what you can do is query for values lower than `\uf8ff`. That's a very high code point in the Unicode range. Since it is after most regular characters in Unicode, this query will return everything that is of type `String`:

```
firestore.collection('employees').where(`equipments.${equipm‌​entId}`, '<', '\uf8ff')
```

Or you can simply query for values higher than "" (empty `String`):

```
firestore.collection('employees').where(`equipments.${equipm‌​entId}`, '>', '')
```

Comment: Even easier is >= ""

Comment: Wow, I wonder how I did not think of that. Thank you @DanMcGrath

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work for fields with document references  unfortunately.

Comment: please note that `!=` and `not-in` are: `Neither query operator will match documents where the specified field is not present.`
[firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_3)

Answer (score 31):

FWIW since Firestore indexes are sparse [1] you can do something like:

```
firestore.collection('employees').orderBy(`equipments.${equipm‌​entId}`)
```

And you'll only get documents where that field is set. If you're explicitly setting the fields to `null` in your database, however, you'll get null values first, so if you want to avoid explicit null values you can do:

```
firestore.collection('employees').orderBy('equipments.${equipm‌​entId}').startAfter(null);
```

[1]: Sparse in the sense that if the field is not present in the document, Cloud Firestore does not create an index entry in the index for that document/field.

Comment: Thank you @rockwotj, the `.startAfter(null)` was just what I needed!