# firestore security rule resource.data is empty object

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In firestore security rule, the resource.data is an emtpy object always, is this a bug or something ?

My firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /hospitals/{document=**}{

      // allow read :if resource.data.size() == 0; //this return true, resource.data is an empty object

          allow read :if resource.data.name != null; // this doesn't work
    }
  }
}
```

My javascript:

```
auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { 
  if (user) {

    //db is the firestore instance
    db.collection('/hospitals').get()
      .then(printResult)

  } else {
    
  }
})
```

this is my current database snapshot
[image]

## solved :

thanks for Frank's answer

the issue rely on that firestore security doesn't evaluate the actual document value when we query a over multiple document , in my case

```
//this doesn't firestore doesnt' evaluate the documetn
db.collection('hospitals').get()

//this will work ,if you need to compare the actual value
db.document('hospitals/somehospital').get()
```

Comment: i corrected my question, my apology

Comment: Even with the update, it's hard to say what's going on without seeing the code that is giving you unexpected results. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to make it easiest to help you.

Comment: i added my javasript code above

Comment: when i use the rule " // allow read :if resource.data.size() == 0; " , i am able to retrieve all the document, but i failed when i try to access the "resource.data.name != null"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Security rules don't filter data by themselves. They merely enforce rules on what data a client can read. Your client is currently trying to read all hospitals. Since your security rules have restrictions on what data a client can read, they reject this operation.

You need to ensure that what your client requests is no more than what the security rules allow, by reading the data through a query that matches the security rules. So something like

```
db.collection('/hospitals')
  .where("name", ">=", "")
  .get()
  .then(printResult)
```

Note that this does require that the document has a `name` field, otherwise the name can't be empty.

For more info, see:

- the [Firestore documentation on securing queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query)
- [Firestore select where is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479532/firestore-select-where-is-not-null)

Comment: From the documentation [Firestore documentation on securing queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query)
**To save you time and resources, Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential result set instead of the actual field values for all of your documents.**   does it mean when we query multiple documents at a time, firestore security rule would not evaluate the the actual value for each document?