# Resource Object in Firestore rules only able to access keys which are in composite index

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
function isWriter(request,resource) {
  return ('writerIds' in resource.data) && resource.data.writerIds == request.auth.uid;
}

 match /bookmarks/{bookmarks} {
    allow read: if  isWriter(request,resource)
}
```

In my bookmark collection, When I put the accessible writer's id into writerIds key then this rules fails but if i change the key to studentId and change the rule into below mentioned way, then it works

```
   function isWriter(request,resource) {
  return ('studentId' in resource.data) && resource.data.studentId == request.auth.uid;
}

 match /bookmarks/{bookmarks} {
    allow read: if isWriter(request,resource)
}
```

The only differnece between both the keys is that studentId is a composite index but writerIds is not.

My Document looks like

```
{isBookmark:boolean, studentId:string, writerIds:string}
```

I have also tried with the partial conditions as well by changing the isWriter Function to this for both studentId and writerIds but this behaves same as above.

```
function isWriter(request,resource) {return ('writerIds' in resource.data)}
```

Is it possible that resource object only access the keys which are composite index?

Comment: I don't believe a composite index has anything to do with security rules. How are you setting the values for the `writerIds` and `studentId` fields so you can compare them to `request.auth.uid`? Can you also show the contents of the document and the queries that you're using or how you are testing the rules?

Comment: @ÁlvaroZamora I am testing it by setting values manually like i kept same values in both the fields but one passed and one didn't. I don't think this is something related to value/content mismatch because if that is the case then at least "function isWriter(request,resource) {return ('writerIds' in resource.data)} " this condition should have passed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [security rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules):

"[...] when Cloud Firestore applies your security rules, it evaluates the query against its potential result set, not against the actual properties of documents in your database. If a query could potentially include documents that violate your security rules, the query will fail."

So, in your case, the issue is likely in the query you're executing. I replicated your document and ran some tests:

This would NOT work with your security rule:

```js
db.collection('/bookmarks')
        .get()
```

However this would work:

```js
db.collection('/bookmarks')
        .where("writerIds", ">=", "")
        .get()
```

I also found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098585/firestore-security-rule-resource-data-is-empty-object) with a similar issue if you want to see another example.