# Firestore Query for Doubles

Tags: jquery, firebase, null, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Firestore query I want to perform but I can't seem to figure it out. Lets say I have a database structured something similar to this:

```
Groups (collection) 
  groupID
    Members (Array)
      uid1: Double
      uid2: Double
      etc.
```

I want to query all groups in which uid3 exists.

I want to do something similar to this, but unfortunately this is not possible:

```
groupRef.where("Members.uid3", "!=", null)
```

I have looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479532/firestore-select-where-is-not-null?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it only provides a solution dealing with Strings. Is there a similar solution for Doubles? Worst case I could use Strings to represent my Doubles and then query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this kind of query is not possible. My solution was to represent the Double as a String and then use the solution in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479532/firestore-select-where-is-not-null?noredirect=1&lq=1).