# Issue in Order by in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to return all documents having specific field as null when we apply orderBy on that specific field in collection in firestore

For example
I have a 2 document one having "createdDate" field and other not.
I make a query to orderMy Date acc to "createdDate field".
`firestore.collection("collection").orderBy("createdDate").get()`

The result I am getting has only 1 record, that record contains createdDate and It skipped that document that doesn't have "createdDate" field

But I want all the documents

Comment: Hi Geetanshu, you may want to complete the queston with code sample, this could help answers. 
Also, this is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479532/firestore-select-where-is-not-null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore select where is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479532/firestore-select-where-is-not-null)

Comment: I have explained It more, Is it okay now ?

Comment: Hmm. You're asking to order a collection of documents by a field that may not exist? What would the expected result be? That's kind of a design flaw as well which may lead to other trouble down the road. In other words, if I wanted to get a list of user names from a users collection, if I order by their name, what would the expected name be for the users that don't have that field at all? Also, what if I wanted to also get a count of users that actually have a name field? If the ones that don't are returned, the count would be wrong. Better to ensure the name field exists with a null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Firebaser here]* this is an intrinsic limitation of Firestore, when you `orderBy` a field you filter out all documents that do not have that field.

There is no way to query documents which **do not** have a certain field in Firestore.

That said there is a difference between **no value** and **null value**.  If you store `null` in the field by default, you can query for that.