# Lack of null inequality support in Firestore's PHP SDK

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We are able to run null inequality just fine on the JavaScript SDK (client or admin), but we are unable to in PHP? To me it seems this is a backend feature which is already supported by Firestore, but throws an error in PHP.

```
->where('preorders', '!=', null)
```

`Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Null and NaN are allowed only with operator EQUALS.`

Whereas the equivalent in JS SDK works just fine.

```
query(q, where('preorders', '!=', null))
```

Since I cannot open an issue in google's PHP SDK repo [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore), is there any way we can find a reason as to why this is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_) says, :

“A field exists when it's set to any value, including an empty `string (" ")`, `null`, and `NaN` (not a number). Note that null field values do not match `!=` clauses, because `x != null` evaluates to undefined.”

**Explanation** : Yes, even if we add an empty string, null,( supported data type in `Firestore`) or NaN, it doesn't mean that the field doesn't exist. It definitely exists and holds one of those values. And coming to when we compare `x != null` in `where` clauses, `x != null` evaluates undefined, but for non-exist fields. And undefined is not a supported data type in Firestore,  according to  this [Firestore supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).
So we can compare `.where(x!=null)` and it is supported, but it evaluates to undefined for non-existent fields.

As mentioned in similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479532/firestore-select-where-is-not-null/48481812#48481812), the [version release of v7.21.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7210_-_september_17_2020) in Firestore JS SDK supports the `!=` operator with `where` clause from version 7.21.0
But while digging deeper in the documentation, I found that php5 supports `!=` operator as you can see in the [code snippet](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#php_5), but the php8 does not support `!=` operator yet and the workaround is using `not-in` instead of it as shown in this [code snippet](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#php_8).
Maybe you are trying to use php version >5 and hence the error.
There is already an [open issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/4060) on this, in GitHub. You may follow the link for updates and changes or you can create a new request [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=1192449&pli=1).

Comment: What do you mean by `x != null evaluates to undefined in PHP`?
Running `var_dump(4 != null)` returns true, not undefined.

Also, I don't see any point in the lack of support, since this is processed in Firestore's backend, not clientside. Therefore, I think this is a lack of implementation in PHP on the client side, not allowing null with inequality operator.

Comment: I have edited the answer please have a look at it and let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I fully understand how "null" works in document fields, and I am not expecting to find documents which don't have that specific field set, in my snapshot. What I was wondering is why the lack of null inequality in PHP, since this is a backend feature (firestore) and not a client side operation. 

But your link to the snippets explains it. As I guessed, there's no real reason why it is not supported in the latest PHP SDKs aside the lack of implementation on Google's end.